# Send STOMP ERROR from Spring Websocket program

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I have a Spring Websocket Stomp application that accepts SUBSCRIBE requests.

In application I have a handler for SUBSCRIBE, that is,

```
 @Component
 public class SubscribeStompEventHandler implements ApplicationListener<SessionSubscribeEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {}
 }
```

that I use to validate subscription.

I would check something in the *onApplicationEvent* and send STOMP ERROR message back to client from this function.

I found this recipe [How to send ERROR message to STOMP clients with Spring WebSocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741511/how-to-send-error-message-to-stomp-clients-with-spring-websocket) but I need to understand how to get outboundChannel.

I tried also the following code:

```
   public void sendStompError(SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate, String sessionId, String topic, String errorMessage) {

    StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.create(StompCommand.ERROR);
    headerAccessor.setMessage(errorMessage);
    headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
    headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId, topic, new byte[0], headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());       
}
```

and I tried topic to be some subsciption topic and /queue/error topic. However I did not see messages propagating to client.

In Client, I use:

```
      stompClient.connect(headers
                , function (frame) {
                    console.log("Conn OK " + url);               
                }, function (error) {                       
                    console.log("Conn NOT OK " + url + ": " + JSON.stringify(error));
                });
        }
```

and my goal is to have function(error) called when I send STOMP ERROR.

Please advice me how exactly I can send proper STOMP ERROR, e.g. by getting Outboundchannel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can send `ERROR` Message like this:

```
StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.create(StompCommand.ERROR);
headerAccessor.setMessage(error.getMessage());
headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
this.clientOutboundChannel.send(MessageBuilder.createMessage(new byte[0], headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders()));
```

The following is just enough to inject that `clientOutboundChannel`:

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("clientOutboundChannel")
 private MessageChannel clientOutboundChannel;
```

Just because `clientOutboundChannel` bean is declared in the `AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration`.

**UPDATE**

> STOMP ERROR always closes connection? I am getting this effect. Code 1002.

Yes, it is. See `StompSubProtocolHandler.sendToClient()`:

```
       if (StompCommand.ERROR.equals(command)) {
            try {
                session.close(CloseStatus.PROTOCOL_ERROR);
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                // Ignore
            }
        }
```

Comment: Artem, can you clarify please: STOMP ERROR always closes connection? I am getting this effect. Code 1002.

Comment: See and UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: How StompClient receive error message? Any special configuration?

Comment: Since `StompCommand.ERROR` always closed a connection, then we don't have choice and send errors to the client as regular `StompCommand.MESSAGE`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan do you know of any alternative using SpringBoot to properly send ERROR frames and wait some time till client can process them?

Comment: how to get a session to close the connection?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I tried that and I get the error: ```ERROR [tboundChannel-7] [ng.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler] Could not find session id in GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=OTHER, stompCommand=ERROR, nativeHeaders={message=[Access is denied]}}]```

Comment: You have to set it into that error message manually: `headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);`

Comment: @ArtemBilan Where I get the `sessionId` from? My code: <pre> <br/>[code block]
 @MessageExceptionHandler  
@SendTo("/topic/versions")  
public String handleEx(Throwable e) {
 StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.create(StompCommand.ERROR);
 headerAccessor.setMessage(exception.getMessage());
 headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);

 clientOutboundChannel.send(MessageBuilder.createMessage(new byte[0], headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders()));
 return e.getMessage();
}[code block]<code>

Comment: Found how to get sessionId: ```
    @MessageExceptionHandler
    @SendTo("/topic/versions")
    public String handleException(Throwable exception, @Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId) {
 StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.create(StompCommand.ERROR);
 headerAccessor.setMessage(exception.getMessage());
 headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);

 clientOutboundChannel.send(MessageBuilder.createMessage(new byte[0], headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders()));
 return exception.getMessage();
}```

Comment: Sorry, the long, multi-line code in comments are not readable. Please, consider next time to raise a new SO thread with all and properly formatted info.